# Unable to load driverless ai models with pb and toml formats in the same JVM

Tags: h2o, driverless-ai

I'm trying to use results of two models built in h2o driverless ai. One of them was built in 1.6.0 version and the other one was built in latest 1.7.0 version.
When I try to load the pipeline.mojo of these two models(One of them will be in pb format and the other one in toml format) in my java application, the first model file is read fine where as it throws IllegalArgumentException when reading the second model file in the same JVM instance.

The mojo2-runtime jar that is being used is from 1.7.0 version.

```
String toml_fileName = "/usr/toml/pipeline.mojo";
MojoPipeline toml_model = MojoPipeline.loadFrom(toml_fileName);

String pb_fileName = "/usr/pb/pipeline.mojo";
MojoPipeline pb_model = MojoPipeline.loadFrom(pb_fileName);
```

I get the following exception while trying to load the second model file which is pb_model in my case.

Can someone help me in finding out what's going wrong?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.b.aj.a(SourceFile:62)
    at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.b.J.a(SourceFile:35)
    at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.readers.MojoReader.read(SourceFile:133)
    at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.readers.MojoTransformerReader.readExecPipeTransformer(SourceFile:311)
    at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.readers.MojoTransformerReader.read(SourceFile:41)
    at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.readers.MojoReader.read(SourceFile:121)
    at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.MojoPipelineFactoryImpl.loadFrom(SourceFile:59)
    at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.MojoPipelineFactoryImpl.loadFrom(SourceFile:22)
    at ai.h2o.mojos.runtime.MojoPipeline.loadFrom(SourceFile:41)
```

Comment: Could you please specify the version of runtime backend are you using? My recommendation would be to use the latest mojo runtime backend: ```implementation 'ai.h2o:mojo2-runtime-api:2.1.3'``` and ```implementation 'ai.h2o:mojo2-runtime-impl:2.1.3'``` (if you are using latest Gradle).

Comment: Hi, The runtime version 2.0.1 was being used and the above mentioned 2.1.3 solves the issue. Thanks for the help !